# How to code android app in small line of code?

Tags: android, mobile-development

I am developing android app using android studio and java. But I found that I have to write code too lengthy. Can any other way to code android app with less line of code.

Comment: use kotlin instead of java

Comment: Look into Flutter

Answer (score 2):

in the menu, Preferences -> Appearance and Behavior -> Appearance, then check Override default font. Then you can make the font size smaller.